# Who got the matnas kahunah before the Egel?

Tags: kohen-priest, levites-leviyim, bechor-firstborn

In the beginning the Avodah (service) of Karbonos was with the bechor (first-born -- see the mishnah in the last perek of Zevachim. The avodah was done by the bechorim until the Mishkan was built) until after they made the egel ha'zahav. Then the Avodah was given to the Kohanim and Shevet Levi. They (Kohanim) received matnas kahunah (chozeh, shuk, etc) because of their service in the Mishkan (and Beis Hamikdash.)

Before the egel ha'zahav to whom would these presents be given to? The bechorim?

Comment: no one, because Trumot and Maaserot are only applicable in the land of Israel.

Comment: @Menachem Moreover, they only became obligatory in Israel after the land was conquered by Joshua.

Comment: @Menachem, DoubleAA, sounds like an answer. Why not post it as such?

Comment: It can still be asked; what would've happened had the episode not taken place?

Comment: maybe clarify that in question?

Comment: At http://kehuna.org/%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-here-and-now/ you can find the 24 matnot kehuna of which it says, “Of the twenty-four kohanic gifts mentioned in the torah and listed by chazal, eight have applicability even outside the land of Israel with some permitted for consumption by the kohen only outside of Israel.” Take a look there.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok That's somewhat misleading. Teruma in Israel can be eaten, just the Kohein requires a higher level of purity than he requires outside of Israel. There is no gift which can _only_ be eaten outside of Israel.